# Material UI 5 Collapse Width and Animation Issue

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

MUI5 Collapse closing animation is working fine but on expanding its not smooth.
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-matsumoto-ekw7nt?file=/src/App.js

The child element of collapse which is a box in this case should take 100% width of the collapse container.

Comment: if you set width for the wrapper box of typograohy  it will smoothly extend and collapse. I dont know why exactly. try to something like width:450px on the box and see the result

Comment: you are right, if using fixed width it works fine but at the end i want it to take full width of the parent container so fixed length wont do the job the way i want, still i appreciate it.  @amir_70